# sqlite: count and group by clause gives not the result expected

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, having

on sqlite, I have the tables

```
papers: rero_id, doi, year
writtenby: rero_id, authorid, instid
authors: author_id, name, firstname
inst: inst_id, name, see_id
```

inst is a table of Institutions: Universities and so on.
Each line in writtenby gives a paper, an author, an institution this author was attached at that time. There can be more then one institution and the couple paper, authorid is repeated for each institution.
For a given author, I want a list and a count of the institutions he has cohautored paper with.
For a list I tried

```
SELECT  inst.name as loc
FROM (
(authors INNER JOIN writtenby ON authors.authorid = 
      writtenby.authorid) 
      INNER JOIN writtenby AS writtenby_1 ON writtenby.rero_id = 
       writtenby_1.rero_id

 ) 

 INNER JOIN authors AS auth_1 ON writtenby_1.authorid = 
 auth_1.authorid
 inner join inst on  writtenby_1.instid = inst.inst_id 

 WHERE (authors.name) ="Doe" AND (authors.firstname)= "Joe"
 ORDER BY loc
```

I got a list that seems ok.

Now, I would like to regroup these institution names and have a count.
I tried

```
 SELECT  inst.name, count(inst.name)
 FROM (
    (authors INNER JOIN writtenby ON authors.authorid = 
     writtenby.authorid) 
     INNER JOIN writtenby AS writtenby_1 ON writtenby.rero_id = 
     writtenby_1.rero_id

 ) 

 INNER JOIN authors AS auth_1 ON writtenby_1.authorid = 
 auth_1.authorid
 inner join inst on  writtenby_1.instid = inst.inst_id 
 GROUP BY inst.name
 HAVING (authors.name) ="Doe" AND (authors.firstname)= "John"
```

I have only three line and not a count of the institutions listed from the first query. 
Thanks for correcting me !

François

Comment: In Standard SQL this will fail, because HAVING is applied *after* aggregation and there's no more row with an `authors.name`, must be `min(authors.name)` or `max`

Answer (score 0):

Try using where instead of having

```
 SELECT  inst.name, count(inst.name)
 FROM (
    (authors INNER JOIN writtenby ON authors.authorid = 
     writtenby.authorid) 
     INNER JOIN writtenby AS writtenby_1 ON writtenby.rero_id = 
     writtenby_1.rero_id

 ) 

 INNER JOIN authors AS auth_1 ON writtenby_1.authorid = 
 auth_1.authorid
 inner join inst on  writtenby_1.instid = inst.inst_id 
 where authors.name ='Doe' AND authors.firstname= 'John' 
 GROUP BY inst.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this that works,

```
SELECT inst.name as loc, count(*) as c
FROM (
(authors INNER JOIN writtenby ON authors.authorid = writtenby.authorid) 
INNER JOIN writtenby AS writtenby_1 ON writtenby.rero_id = 
writtenby_1.rero_id
inner join inst on  writtenby_1.instid = inst.inst_id 
) 
INNER JOIN authors AS auth_1 ON writtenby_1.authorid = auth_1.authorid
WHERE (authors.name) ="Doe" AND (authors.firstname)= "John"
GROUP BY inst.name
ORDER BY c DESC
```

I still can use a where clause, and that's not the same as having...
And thanks to [fa6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6914864/fa06) who gave the answer below
F.